# CKEDITOR link issues

Tags: php

I am using CKEDITOR in my small CMS.

When I am using the link function local it's working fine. But as soon as I got online, and tried to make a link mysql_real_escape_string(); is messing things up and I get links like:

```
<a href=\"\\\" target=\"\\&quot;_blank\\&quot;\">Se beautyPopup p&aring; gitHub</a>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on? And why?

Comment: @PeeHaa I am using mysql_real_escape_string() on the content given in the ckeditor textarea to avoid scripts performed from output from database.

Comment: So you are basically saying your are using `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape HTML output?

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried to write ;)

Comment: Do you see this string in the database or the browser? Show us the fragment of code that you are using to store/display the data.

Comment: This string is in database.

Comment: @SalmanA I've started learning PDO instead, so this question is kinda useless in some way :) Thanks to everyone who've used their time on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is because you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape HTML output. That's not what it is for. It is to escape data going in the database.

What you are looking for is: [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Also don't forget about passing in the encoding. An example of this is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($yourString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Also note that if you are working on new code you aren't encouraged to use the old `mysql_*` API in PHP anyway, because it has been [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

*UPDATE*

Based on your comment I see that you are trying to preserve some tags while disallowing other tags. In that case I can only suggest you to look into [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: That just messed things up even more. Now <p></p> tags is handled as plain text too.

Comment: So at the end of the day Madara Uchiha is right, and I should use MySQLi instead?

Comment: You should use either `mysqli` or `PDO`, but if you are escaping HTML output with mysql functions (whether `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*`) you are doing it wrong either way.

Comment: First, why should'nt I use mysql_real_escape_string() on $_POST['content']? It's going to the database to.

Comment: In [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095000/ckeditor-link-issues/14095145#comment19496812_14095000) you stated you used it to escape HTML output instead of database input. Basically what I am saying is there is no silver bullet when in comes to escaping. You need to use the method for the specific purpose.

Comment: Oh, I've misunderstood you then. I am using mysql_real_escape_string() for data going to database.